# CMake linking fails when linking two SDK libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

On windows 10 64 bit using Cygwin for tool-chain. I am completely new to C++.

**The problem:** When building the project I receive a number of undefined reference errors. Since I do not receive any other errors, I suspect that the linker is having issues linking the libraries. Error messages below:

```
C:\Users\xxx\.CLion2017.3\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build 
C:\PhD\test\ICMI2017Demo\cmake-build-debug --target ICMI2017Demo -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ICMI2017Demo.exe
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `LeapToUHDirection':  /cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:14: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::Alignment::fromTrackingDirectionToDeviceDirection(Ultrahaptics::Vector3 const&) const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:14:(.text+0xf0): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::Alignment::fromTrackingDirectionToDeviceDirection(Ultrahaptics::Vector3 const&) const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `LeapToUHPosition':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:21: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::Alignment::fromTrackingPositionToDevicePosition(Ultrahaptics::Vector3 const&) const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:21:(.text+0x153): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::Alignment::fromTrackingPositionToDevicePosition(Ultrahaptics::Vector3 const&) const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `emitterCallback(Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter const&, Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputInterval&, Ultrahaptics::HostTimePoint const&, void*)':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:94: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputInterval::begin()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:94:(.text+0x82b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputInterval::begin()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:94: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputInterval::end()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:94:(.text+0x83b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputInterval::end()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:94: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator<(Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator const&) const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:94:(.text+0x84b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator<(Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator const&) const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator->()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:100:(.text+0x8bb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator->()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::TimePointOnOutputInterval::persistentControlPoint(unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:100:(.text+0x8c8): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::TimePointOnOutputInterval::persistentControlPoint(unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:101: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator->()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:101:(.text+0x8ec): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator->()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:101: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::TimePointOnOutputInterval::persistentControlPoint(unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:101:(.text+0x8f9): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::TimePointOnOutputInterval::persistentControlPoint(unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator->()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:103:(.text+0x91e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator->()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::TimePointOnOutputInterval::persistentControlPoint(unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:103:(.text+0x92b): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:104: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator->()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:104: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::TimePointOnOutputInterval::persistentControlPoint(unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:94: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputIntervalIterator::operator++()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:145: undefined reference to `Leap::Controller::Controller()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:146: undefined reference to `Leap::Controller::setPolicyFlags(Leap::Controller::PolicyFlag) const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:147: undefined reference to `Leap::Controller::addListener(Leap::Listener&)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:150: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter::Emitter()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:151: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter::setMaximumControlPointCount(unsigned int)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:156: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter::setEmissionCallback(void (*)(Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter const&, Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::OutputInterval&, Ultrahaptics::HostTimePoint const&, void*), void*)'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:157: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter::start()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:189: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter::stop()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:191: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter::start()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.cpp:150: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::TimePointStreaming::Emitter::~Emitter()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:8: undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::Alignment::Alignment()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `TranslatedBone::TranslatedBone(Leap::Bone const&)':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:33: undefined reference to `Leap::Bone::nextJoint() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:34: undefined reference to `Leap::Bone::prevJoint() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:36: undefined reference to `Leap::Bone::basis() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:48: undefined reference to `Leap::Bone::type() const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `TranslatedFinger::TranslatedFinger(Leap::Finger&)':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:77: undefined reference to `Leap::Pointable::tipVelocity() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:79: undefined reference to `Leap::Bone::Bone()'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:84: undefined reference to `Leap::Finger::bone(Leap::Bone::Type) const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::Pointable::~Pointable()':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:129: undefined reference to `Leap::Interface::~Interface()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::Pointable::~Pointable()':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:129: undefined reference to `Leap::Interface::~Interface()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `TranslatedHand::TranslatedHand(Leap::Hand const&)':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:98: undefined reference to `Leap::Hand::basis() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:99: undefined reference to `Leap::Hand::basis() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:100: undefined reference to `Leap::Hand::basis() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:101: undefined reference to `Leap::Hand::palmPosition() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:102: undefined reference to `Leap::Hand::palmVelocity() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:103: undefined reference to `Leap::Hand::palmNormal() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:105: undefined reference to `Leap::Hand::fingers() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:105: undefined reference to `Leap::FingerList::begin() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/HapticSurface/LeapMotionDataConversion.hpp:105: undefined reference to `Leap::FingerList::end() const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `LeapListening::onFrame(Leap::Controller const&)':
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.h:48: undefined reference to `Leap::Controller::frame(int) const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.h:49: undefined reference to `Leap::Frame::hands() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.h:53: undefined reference to `Leap::HandList::isEmpty() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.h:62: undefined reference to `Leap::HandList::begin() const'
/cygdrive/c/PhD/test/ICMI2017Demo/main.h:62: undefined reference to `Leap::HandList::end() const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::ConstListIterator<Leap::FingerList, Leap::Finger>::operator*() const':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:3448: undefined reference to `Leap::FingerList::operator[](int) const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::ConstListIterator<Leap::HandList, Leap::Hand>::operator*() const':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:3448: undefined reference to `Leap::HandList::operator[](int) const'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::Frame::~Frame()':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:4634: undefined reference to `Leap::Interface::~Interface()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::HandList::~HandList()':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:3883: undefined reference to `Leap::Interface::~Interface()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::Hand::~Hand()':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:1096: undefined reference to `Leap::Interface::~Interface()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::Bone::~Bone()':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:662: undefined reference to `Leap::Interface::~Interface()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Leap::FingerList::~FingerList()':
C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/Leap.h:3622: undefined reference to `Leap::Interface::~Interface()'
CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN12Ultrahaptics9AlignmentD1Ev[.refptr._ZN12Ultrahaptics9AlignmentD1Ev]+0x0): undefined reference to `Ultrahaptics::Alignment::~Alignment()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/build.make:98: ICMI2017Demo.exe] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/ICMI2017Demo.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: ICMI2017Demo] Error 2
```

**I have tried**: I have used different approaches to linking my libraries such as relative path(didn't work), absolute paths(showed the aforementioned error), used CMake environment variables to specify path(same error). I have also tried re-downloading/reinstalling the SDKs(also making sure they follow the 64 bit system) and no change. Last, I have tried copying the library files in a folder in the project solution(in case the linker just couldn't handle searching somewhere outside of it) but still the same error.

The **reason** for posting in SO and not to the respective websites is because I receive undefined error mesages on both SDKs(Leap Motion SDK and Ultrahaptic), therefore leaning towards my incompetency rather than a specific library fault.

Please do give advice and any possible ideas.

Last my current CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Include the Ultrahaptics SDK
find_package(Ultrahaptics)

set(ULTRAHAPTICS_INCLUDE_DIR /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Ultrahaptics/include/)
include_directories(${ULTRAHAPTICS_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Include the Leap Motion SDK
include_directories(C:/PhD/code/libraries/LeapSDK/include/)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp main.h )
add_executable(Demo ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Link the Ultrahaptics and Leap Motion libraries
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/)
set(ULTRAHAPTICS_LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/libusb-1.0.lib ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/Ultrahaptics.lib)
target_link_libraries(Demo ${ULTRAHAPTICS_LIBRARIES} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/Leap.lib)
```

Comment: Are you sure this library was built with the same compiler you are using?

Comment: That is something I have completely neglected to check.Indeed it is compiled with a different compiler. I will have a look and come back with the results.

Comment: Visual Studio and gcc have different ABIs, so they generate object files which are not binary compatible. When you want to link against particular library you need to be sure which compiler was used for it.

Comment: Coming back to this, indeed that was the problem! I have changed to Visual Studio with the Visual C++ compiler and the issues disappeared as soon as I linked the libraries(one of the two libraries was not compatible with the Cygwin compiler I have installed). Even though I still have other issues this specific question has been answered.